# Postgresql select rows(a result) as array

Tags: postgresql

Assume I have following table, plus some data.

```
create table "common"."log"("id" bigserial primary key, 
                            "level" int not null default 0);
```

Now I have this select query that would return something like this.
`select * from common.log where id=147;`

```
+------+--------+
|id    |level   |
+------+--------+
|147   |1       |
|147   |2       |
|147   |2       |
|147   |6       |
|147   |90      |
+------+--------+
```

Now I like to have something like following rather above

```
+------+---------------+
|id    |arr_level      |
+------+---------------+
|147   |{1,2,2,6,90}   |
+------+---------------+
```

So is there any implicit select clause/way for doing this? thanks.

`pgsql v9.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user array function like this

```
 Select '147' as id,array(select level from common.log where id=147) as arr_level;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, probably more useful if you have more than one id to query:

```
SELECT id, array_agg(level) FROM common.log GROUP BY id;
```

See: [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).