# Set results to be array in a new column for over a million rows -postgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying to get all the photo urls into an array and set that array to be a new column in a different table.  The tables have a one to many relationship.  I have about 1 million rows on my list_reviews table and around 3 million photos.

Is there a way to do this in batches? When I tried to do it all in one shot I just got empty arrays.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20051219121211.002f7e87.gry@ll.mit.edu and [Postgresql select rows(a result) as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671608/postgresql-select-rowsa-result-as-array)

Those work if I am only doing one at a time.  I have been thinking about trying to use the STREAMING found here, https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#into-database but not sure I totally understand what is going on here.

```
CREATE TABLE list_reviews (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INT,
  photos TEXT[]);

CREATE TABLE review_photos (
  id SERIAL,
  review_id INT REFERENCES list_reviews(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  url TEXT);

UPDATE list_reviews SET photos = array(
   SELECT url
   FROM review_photos
   WHERE review_photos.id = list_reviews.id 
   AND list_reviews.id = 5);
```

list_reviews looks like:

```
+----+------------+--------+--+
| id | product_id | photos |  |
+----+------------+--------+--+
|  5 |          1 | []     |  |
+----+------------+--------+--+
```

review_photos looks like:

```
+----+-----------+------------+--+
| id | review_id |   photos   |  |
+----+-----------+------------+--+
|  1 |         5 | something1 |  |
|  2 |         5 | something2 |  |
|  3 |         5 | something3 |  |
+----+-----------+------------+--+
```

and would expect to see list_reviews:

```
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+--+
| id | product_id |                photos                |  |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+--+
|  5 |          1 | [something1, something2, something3] |  |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically looks okay.  I prefer using `array_agg()` (because the operation is more explicit), but Postgres allows a result set for `array`.

One issue is the filtering.  I think you intend:

```
UPDATE list_reviews lr
    SET photos = array(SELECT rp.url
                       FROM review_photos rp
                       WHERE rp.id = lr.id 
                      )
    WHERE lr.id = 5;
```

Your query will update all rows in `list_reviews` with the urls from the photos for id = 5.

You can do this in batches by putting ranges on `lr.id` as you do the processing.  For instance:

```
UPDATE list_reviews lr
    SET photos = array(SELECT rp.url
                       FROM review_photos rp
                       WHERE rp.id = lr.id 
                      )
    WHERE lr.id > 0 and lr.id < 10000;
```

However, it might be simpler to replace the existing table:

```
create temporary table temp_list_reviews as
    select id, product_id,  -- all columns but photos
           array(SELECT rp.url
                           FROM review_photos rp
                           WHERE rp.id = lr.id 
                          ) as photos
    from list_reviews;

truncate table list_reviews;

insert into list_reviews (id, product_id, photos)
    select id, product_id, photo
    from temp_list_reviews;
```

Bulk inserts are usually faster than updates, due to logging considerations.